# socket.io in useEffect produces Proxy Error (ECONNRESET)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, socket.io, react-hooks

## Summary

I've built a prototype for an app that is going to have some sort of chat functionality. As of right now the frontend `React` just pulls data via `useEffect`. To implement a more dynamic chat feeling I thought about using `socket.io`. When instantiating socket.io client-side as suggested (in useEffect) I am getting an ECONNRESET error.

## Setup:

- **Backend:** Node.js + express.js (listening on Port 5000)
- **Frontend:** React
- **Frontend:** Proxy for local development in package.json like this `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"`

## Problem:

When initializing my socket client-side like this:

```
const Flow = () => {

    ...

    const fetchsocketData = () => {
        const socket = io();
        console.log("trying socket stuff");
        socket.on("FromBackEnd", data => {console.log(data)});
    };
    useEffect(() => fetchsocketData(),[])

    ...

    return (<div>Yolo</div>)
}
```

The proxying (as defined in the package.json) works nicely with e.g. Axios-calls, however, with socket.io, I get the following error on the **server-side**:

> Proxy error: Could not proxy request
>   /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N5v5GOe&sid=yugXlgWYsoqJRqcxAAAT
>   from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000. See
>   https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for
>   more information (ECONNRESET).

And the following error on the **client-side**:

> websocket.js:116 WebSocket connection to
>   'ws://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=QKMDK2qmVGT3eud2AAAA'
>   failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code:
>   400

This seems to be a temporal thing though, as the socket.io-connection is ultimately established and emits the test messages.

To make things a little weirder: If I move the socket instantiation into a user-triggered event:

```
const manuallyInstantiateSocket = () => {
    const socket = io();
    console.log("trying socket stuff");
    socket.on("FromBackEnd", data => {console.log(data)});
}
```

And call this on a click of a button all works as expected. No error on the back-end side of things. The front-end error persists though.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try with passing the server uri when creating the socket instance

const manuallyInstantiateSocket = () => {
    const socket = io("http://127.0.0.1:5000");
    console.log("trying socket stuff");
    socket.on("FromBackEnd", data => {console.log(data)});
}

Comment: Hi @Aleksandar, thx for the reply! That does work (I actually had tried this earlier, but forgot to mention it). However, the problem there becomes that in production my IP will be a different one, which is why I really like being able to proxy in development. Any explanation as to why these errors pop up?